# How to call yum install as a Makefile's target

Tags: makefile, yum

How to create a Makefile's target that calls a specific `yum install`:

```
yum install libarchive-devel.x86_64
```

**but only** if the desired package isn't yet installed. Maybe a `yum list installed | grep libarchive` to check...

My goal is to call: `sudo yum install libarchive-devel.x86_64` but only if the package isn't installed yet. A kind of *Maven like* in an abstract way.

Don't need any specific version of it. Only it to be x86_64.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

**»»» below means a tab char**

```
installLib:
»»»rpm -qa | egrep -q libarchive-devel.*64 || sudo yum install --assumeyes libarchive-devel.x86_64
```

This way won't try to install libarchive at each `make`